# Error while running spray akka project with sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, spray

Could you please anyone help me with the below issue, I am getting while running my spray akka project with SBT dependency.

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.timushev.sbt
#sbt-updates;0.1.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;0.11.3: not
found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Thanks.

Comment: Something in your project is trying to pull [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager). I couldn't find a release for version 0.11.3. Maybe the version is incorrectly specified?

Comment: Indeed - there's lots of versions for `sbt-native-packager` at https://index.scala-lang.org/sbt/sbt-native-packager but 0.11.3 isn't one of them.

Comment: Please share your build.sbt file